# How to center a single character both vertically and horizontally in a square div

Tags: css

I want to center within a square div an arbitrary character.  I admit that this sounds like a very simple task, but nothing I've tried works (and I've tried a bazillion things!)<sup>1</sup>.

For concreteness, let's say that the div has height and width equal to 20ex, and let's say that the single character is the so-called "multiplication sign": ✕, nice and symmetric.  I want this character to be positioned inside the 20ex-by-20ex square div such that the point where the two strokes cross is dead-center, both vertically and horizontally, within the div.

EDIT:

I tried the answers I've received so far, [here](http://goo.gl/MZ7N6d).  The solutions given by Jedidiah and by Ashok Kumar Gupta (second and third divs) produce pretty similar results, but (maybe I'm seeing things), the ✕ in the third div is *just a hair* above the vertical center.

---

<sup>1</sup>I have learned that *no matter how mind-numbingly straightforward a layout task may appear*, it can still take me *hours and hours and hours* to figure out the CSS to achieve it.

Comment: Have you tried Marign: 0 auto?

Comment: Ok the answers provided solve the average centering problem. If you want 100% centering that considers all font face specifications (baseline, offset, width, height etc.) you will have to either look for a js library that can get these data from the current font and you apply this via js in order to center your letter or you specify these data in a js script for a specific font you want to use and calculate the position. There are tools that can parse these specifications from any font (ttf).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Setting the line-height to the height of the container should do it.

```
text-align: center;
line-height:20px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/Jedidiah/pen/rLfHz

Comment: Well, will work for the multiplication sign and uppercase letters anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` and `text-align:center`.  Like this in your CSS:

```
#center{
    width:100px;height:100px;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The `display:table-cell` is required to be able to use `vertical-align` to center content in the on the `div` ( don't ask me why someone decided to make it like that ***:)*** ).

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/LvDMa/).

Comment: Are you sure that this considers baseline, bearings, and offsets individually for every character? It's centered but is it really 100% centered https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/topic/com.ibm.aix.graPHIGS/doc/phigstrf/figures/afma5rbd.jpg?

Comment: Sorry, @Layne.  I'm a web developer, not a typeface engineer.

Comment: @Layne It won't work for lowercase or anything with a ascender/descender and neither would mine, answers the question though.

Comment: @Jedidiah yes, I just tested it with lower and upper case characters.

Answer (score 5):

this question is a bit old but it's the first answer when you search "center single letter in square css"

so in 2018 you can simply do

```
#center {

   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

- `justify-content: center` align horizontally
- `align-items: center` align vertically

Note that it will works regardless of the shape of the div, could be a rectangle.

Comment: Works well with current browsers.   Need to add conditional comments + alternate styling for IEs (IE10 doesn't do ` align-items:center; ` )

Comment: Works perfectly in 2019. I recommend changing width/height to `width: 0; height: 0;` if you don't want to peg the size at any specific pixel amount and don't have any nearby content that could get in the way.

Comment: Did you mean to omit the `;` after `height:` ?

Comment: @cazort , no the missing ; was a typo,  I've edited my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is just impossible using css only to center a single character vertically and horizontally in a div because it depends of the font the browser will use to render the character.

For those who just want to center a "X", it is safer to make the "X" transparent, create :before and :after pseudo-elements, give them a thin width and a background that has the same color as the initial "X", then rotate them of + or - 45deg.

HTML code:

```
<div>X</div>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  color: transparent;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "X";
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25em;
  bottom: 0.25em;
  left: 0.9em;
  right: 0.9em;
  background-color: black;
}

div:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z4pmu7r9/

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but after noticing OP's edit:

> I tried the answers I've received so far, here. The solutions given by Jedidiah and by Ashok Kumar Gupta (second and third divs) produce pretty similar results, but (maybe I'm seeing things), the ✕ in the third div is just a hair above the vertical center.

I wanted to post that if you used `&times;` instead of `✕`, the centering looks much better.

https://codepen.io/persianturtle/pen/zPKbRj

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question:

```
<div style="width: 20em;height: 20em; background: red;display: table;">
<p style="display: table-cell;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">X</p></div>
```

Note: background: red; is only for visualization.

:)